# nameko http micro service run fail with cyphon compiled pyd file but py file well

Tags: pyinstaller, cython, nameko

I develop a nameko http micro servie, and it can run well, but if I replace the file myhttp.py with a cyphon compiled file named myhttp.py, I will get [curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8000: Connection refused],please help me.

**step 1: use the below 3 files(build.bat,setup.py,myhttp.py) to generate myhttp.pyd**

build.bat

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    name = 'myapp',
    ext_modules=cythonize("myhttp.py"),
    zip_safe=False,
)
```

myhttp.py

```
from nameko.web.handlers import http
import json
class MyHttpService:
    name = 'my_http_service'
    
    @http('POST','/hello')  #curl -i -d "world" localhost:8000/hello
    def hello(self, request):
        return "Hello, {}!".format(request.get_data(as_text=True))
```

**step 2: use the below 3 files(installer.bat, namekorun.py, namekorun.spec) and generated myhttp.pyd just now to generate namekorun.exe**

installer.bat

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm namekorun.spec
```

namekorun.py

```
import eventlet; 
eventlet.monkey_patch()
from nameko.runners import ServiceRunner
import myhttp
import signal


runner = ServiceRunner(config={'WEB_SERVER_ADDRESS': '0.0.0.0:8000'})
runner.add_service(myhttp.MyHttpService)


def shutdown(signum, frame):
    # signal handlers are run by the MAINLOOP and cannot use eventlet
    # primitives, so we have to call `stop` in a greenlet
    eventlet.spawn_n(runner.stop)

signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, shutdown)
runner.start()
runnlet = eventlet.spawn(runner.wait)
while True:
    try:
        runnlet.wait()
    except OSError as exc:
        if exc.errno == errno.EINTR:
            # this is the OSError(4) caused by the signalhandler.
            # ignore and go back to waiting on the runner
            continue
        raise
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print()  # looks nicer with the ^C e.g. bash prints in the terminal
        try:
            runner.stop()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print()  # as above
            runner.kill()
    else:
        # runner.wait completed
        break
```

namekorun.spec

```
   # -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-
    
    
    block_cipher = None
    
    
    partylibs = ['nameko.constants','nameko.containers','nameko.contextdata','nameko.dependency_providers','nameko.events','nameko.exceptions','nameko.extensions','nameko.log_helpers','nameko.messaging','nameko.rpc','nameko.runners','nameko.serialization','nameko.timer','nameko.amqp.publish','nameko.cli.actions','nameko.cli.backdoor','nameko.cli.code','nameko.cli.commands','nameko.cli.main','nameko.cli.run','nameko.cli.shell','nameko.cli.show_config','nameko.standalone.events','nameko.standalone.rpc','nameko.testing.pytest','nameko.testing.rabbit','nameko.testing.services','nameko.testing.utils','nameko.testing.waiting','nameko.testing.websocket','nameko.utils.retry','nameko.utils.concurrency','nameko.web.handlers','nameko.web.server','nameko.web.websocket']
    
    partylibs += ['eventlet','eventlet.hubs.epolls','eventlet.hubs.kqueue','eventlet.hubs.selects']
    partylibs += ['dns','dns.dnssec','dns.e164','dns.hash','dns.namedict','dns.tsigkeyring','dns.update','dns.version','dns.zone']
    
    a = Analysis(['namekorun.py'],
                 pathex=[],
                 binaries=[],
                 datas=[],
                 hiddenimports=partylibs,
                 hookspath=[],
                 hooksconfig={},
                 runtime_hooks=[],
                 excludes=[],
                 win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
                 win_private_assemblies=False,
                 cipher=block_cipher,
                 noarchive=False)
    pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
                 cipher=block_cipher)
    
    exe = EXE(pyz,
              a.scripts, 
              [],
              exclude_binaries=True,
              name='namekorun',
              debug=False,
              bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
              strip=False,
              upx=True,
              console=True,
              disable_windowed_traceback=False,
              target_arch=None,
              codesign_identity=None,
              entitlements_file=None )
    coll = COLLECT(exe,
                   a.binaries,
                   a.zipfiles,
                   a.datas, 
                   strip=False,
                   upx=True,
                   upx_exclude=[],
                   name='namekorun')
```

step 3: **start dist/namekorun/namekorun.exe, then type** *curl -i -d "world" localhost:8000/hello* **in a command window, and got** *curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8000: Connection refused*, **if replace myhttp.pyd with myhttp.py, it run well**

my package as below and use vs2015

| Package | Version |
| --- | --- |
| python | 3.6.8 |
| Cython | 3.0.0a9 |
| decorator | 4.4.2 |
| eventlet | 0.25.1 |
| kombu | 4.6.8 |
| nameko | 2.12.0 |
| pyinstaller | 4.7 |
| pyinstaller-hooks-contrib | 2021.4 |

Comment: I think you could simplify this a little. Is the Pyinstaller step actually necessary for this problem? Does it work if run from Python directly?

Comment: @DavidW I just had a try.It does not work,  After Compiled into `pyd`(`.so` on linux).And set logging level into `DEBUG`,but it show nothing  when do `curl` which was refused.

Comment: if the `myhttp.py` not compiled by `cython`,and just call other part (compied by `cython`,demo function) in the `hello` method will work well.Any mistake during the `nameko` registe the function,by `http` decorator?

Comment: Thank HaoLan too! for your patience, reproduce my error.

Answer (score 1):

Tracing through the definition of `nameko.web.handlers.http`:

- https://github.com/nameko/nameko/blob/17ecee2bcfa90cb0f3a2f3328c5004f48e4e02a3/nameko/web/handlers.py#L105,
- https://github.com/nameko/nameko/blob/b0862d7f390f4e58f6de847305ad07a48ce127ae/nameko/extensions.py#L312,
- https://github.com/nameko/nameko/blob/b0862d7f390f4e58f6de847305ad07a48ce127ae/nameko/extensions.py#L249-L256

```
setattr(fn, ENTRYPOINT_EXTENSIONS_ATTR, descriptors)
```

Essentially it's trying to set attributes on the function object. Cython functions are a different class to regular Python functions, and that class doesn't have an instance dictionary so `setattr` will fail (I'm slightly surprised you don't get an obvious error about this).

I therefore would not expect this code to work when compiled with Cython.

Comment: Thanks DavidW again! let me know that method is infeasible. I will give up the compiling myhttp.py. in fact, my aim is to hide python source code, as most of files have compiled successfully, not compiling the  file is nothing serious. I have finished my tasks.